# Creating an array of other class.

Tags: java, arrays, class

I want to create an array of class Person in class Donator, but I got this error "error: constructor Person in class Person cannot be applied to given types;"

Did I miss any important code?

Here is my code.

Person.java

```
public class  Person
{
private String Name, Address, Gender, BloodType;
private int ICNumber;
private double Height, Weight;

//constructor
public Person(String n, String add, String gen, String bt, int ic, double h, double w)
{
    Name = n;
    Address = add;
    Gender = gen;
    BloodType = bt;
    ICNumber = ic;
    Height = h;
    Weight = w;
}


//abstract method
//abstract void printPerson();

} //close Person
```

Donator.java

```
public class Donator extends Person
{

private String donatorID;
private Person[] myDonator;
private int numberOfDonator;

//constructor
public Donator(String id, String d)
{
    donatorID = id;
    myDonator = new Person[2];
}

public String getDonatorID()
{
    return donatorID;
}
}//close Donator
```

Comment: You are not showing us all your code, in particular not the line in which the error occurs. The error means you are creating a new `Person` object but you are not supplying the required parameters to the constructor.

Comment: By the way variables are usually written with a small letter in Java and usually in the constructor you should use this keyword

Comment: Show the code of Person Constructor arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are extending `Person` in `Donator` class, you should call super constructor in `Donator` class first.

```
//constructor
public Donator(String id, String d)
{
    // this is the Person constructor.
    super("some string", "some string", "some string", "some string", 1, 1, 1);

    donatorID = id;
    myDonator = new Person[2];
}
```

This is because, the java compiler tries to place the code in your constructor which will call base class's Default constructor, as we don't have the base class default constructor, we get the compilation error.